# flash socket policy files requirement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cross-domain-policy

Last time I worked with flash sockets I knew that a policy file is required only if the swf file is embedded in a different domain from the one where the socket connection is about to be made. 
Did newer version of flash player changed this, so now they'll alk for a policy file no matter what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash Player (since version 9.0.124.0) will not open a socket connection
to a server unless the server first authorizes the connection via an Adobe
socket policy.